# Fix must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

```
select
    case
        when daftar ='sd' then kouta
    end as a,
    case
        when daftar = 'smp' then kouta
    end as b,
    case
        when daftar = 'sma' then kouta
    end as c
from
    ajaran
GROUP BY
    tahun
```

and result error

> [Err] ERROR:  column "ajaran.daftar" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select  case when
>   daftar='sd' then kouta end as a,case when ...

I'm trying same query in MySQL and no error and success grouping
how to use group by in PostgreSQL?

I want to group by `tahun`.

This is my table.

[image: this my table]

Comment: MySQL is incorrect to let the query run without errors, but MySQL is less strict than PostgreSQL (and most other database systems, really).

Comment: What data are you expecting as output? Do you know what `GROUP BY` means? What is the meaning of `tahun` in this context and how does it relate to `kouta`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want `sum()` or `max()` as in:

```
select tahun,
       max(case when daftar = 'sd' then kouta end) as a,
       max(case when daftar = 'smp' then kouta end) as b,
       max(case when daftar = 'sma' then kouta end) as c
from ajaran
group by tahun;
```

I think the error is pretty clear . . . `daftar` and `kouta` are neither keys in the `group by` nor are they in aggregation functions in your query.  Which aggregation is most appropriate is not clear without further guidance, such as sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

When grouping, you must return **one** row per group, but your select doesn't aggregate the values into one row.

Provide an aggregate, for example using `max()`:

```
select
    tahun,
    max(case when daftar ='sd' then kouta end) a,
    max(case when daftar = 'smp' then kouta end) b,
    max(case when daftar = 'sma' then kouta end) c
from ajaran
group by tahun
```